# Find / select / delete dangles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, topology

Via Topologie Checker I'm able to find dangles, but there is no way to select them to edit or remove. Is there an other way to find and select?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that those are all dangles?  Many of them look like true nodes.

Comment: You may be able to find and resolve topological errors using v.clean grass tool in QGIS.

Comment: @PolyGeo: That's just the result of the QGIS "on board" topology checker - every dangle is marked with it's end and it's start node - so it looks right for me

Comment: So it's marking the end nodes of dangling arcs rather than dangling nodes.